# DateTimeField to str and read from str

Tags: django

I have a problem with understating how to deal DateTimeField.
I have model with DateTimeField, view which returns jsons containing this field and another view which use provided data (as string) to filter result

```
# model
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
# first view
return str((self.date.isoformat() for date in ...))
# f. exp: ['2019-11-19T15:22:47.788254+00:00']
# second view
Row.objects.filter(data__lte=data_from_GET)
```

If I have used 2019-11-19T15:22:47.788254+00:00 I reciver error
ValidationError at /csv/
["'2019-11-19T15:22:47.788254+00:00' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

I can not find an easy way (without string manipulation) to return data in a format acceptable by the filter method.

What is interesting:

```
2019-11-19T15:22:47.788254-00:00 not ok
2019-11-19 15:22:47.788254+00:00 not ok
2019-11-19 15:22:47.788254-00:00 ok
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for: `from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime` , `parse_datetime("2019-11-19T15:22:47.788254+00:00")` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use EpochUTC and integer values to compare different dates. If you need to display these dates you can transform them into strings using the `new Date` constructor.